# Address redirected to localhost in redmine

Tags: redirect, debian, redmine

I have problem with redmine.

I installed redmine on debian 6.0 with nginx and postresql
When I want to get to redmine using adres ServerIP/redmine it redirects to localhost/redmine

What could be the problem? I must add that work on debian just starting

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the server ip in nginx configuration file

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/test.com/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name test.com www.test.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}}
```